# Why we can't take vertical cylinder as Gaussian surface to calculate the electric field of an uniformly charged infinite sheet?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

To calculate the electric field due to an uniformly charged infinite sheet, we take a horizontal cylinder as Gaussian surface. But why we can't take a vertical cylinder to do the same?

Comment: But then you can't evaluate $\oint\vec{E}.\vec{ds}$ easily.

Comment: Then how we can do it when we calculate the field of an infinite wire?

Comment: Electric field due to infinite wire and infinite sheet have cylindrical and planar symmetry respectively. So in front of infinite wire we need a closed surface which looks circular when seen from the top (so, vertical cylinder) and in case of infinite wire we need an enclosed surface which is like a plane in front of sheet. So, a cube, cuboid and horizontal cylinder can be used as a Gaussian surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When constructing a Gaussian surface, our main goal is to take advantage of the inherent **symmetry** of the charge distribution.

For an infinite sheet aligned in the $x-z$ plane, there is symmetry along the $x$ and $z$ directions. In other words, we cannot expect any physical characteristics of the system to depend on $x$ or $z$. This includes the $\mathbf{E}$ field generated by the sheet. This symmetry, along with the fact that $\mathbf{E}$ is conservative, allows us to deduce that $\mathbf{E}$ can only have a $y$ component.

[image: E field of infinite sheet of charge]

Now, the Gaussian surface must take advantage of this symmetry we've identified. The choice of a horizontal cylinder does this as follows.

[image: Horizontal cylinder]

The cylinder is constructed such that the rounded sides are parallel to $\mathbf{E}$, while the caps are perpendicular to $\mathbf{E}$. This heavily simplifies the flux through the whole cylindrical surface, which can just be written as the magnitude of $\mathbf{E}$ multiplied by the areas of the caps.

$$\oint\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{ds}=2EA$$

In fact, the surface does not need to be a cylinder. It could simply be a surface that has parallel sides and perpendicular caps.

[image: Arbitrary Surface]

A vertical cylinder, on the other hand, would not take advantage of this symmetry.

[image: Vertical Cylinder]

This is because $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{ds}$ would be different along the surface, and you would need to compute the surface integral without any simplifications.

P.S. I have not indicated the $\mathbf{E}$ fields on the left side of the sheets out of convenience. They still exist.